# What is meant by `compile dependencies in the console`

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, installation, console

I'm trying to install a C++ framework which has a pretty complicated installation process since a binary installer is not provided. Here is the link that shows the steps to take to install this framework. http://fw4spl.readthedocs.io/en/dev/Installation/src/WindowsInstall.html. I'm using Windows 10 if that helps.

I've been able to successfully follow the instructions (hopefully) until this part: `Compile the FW4SPL dependencies with jom in the console (e.g. jom all, jom qt, etc)`. I don't really understand what I am expected to do and what cmd commands I am supposed to use to complete the installation. Also, I don't really understand why there are separate instructions for `dependencies` and `source` since they look exactly the same to me. Am I supposed to do both? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Dependencies** describes (how) to clone a git-repo with software which is _needed_ by `fw4spl`. **Sources** describes (how) to clone git-repo with sources of `fw4spl` (_itself_). I do not know anything about `fw4spl` except what I read when I followed the link you provided. I would recommend to do both (from what I read there). Are you familiar with `git`? If not I recommend to google and learn this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling dependencies and source files are not the same since the instructions say that the `fw4spl-deps` folder must be built and compiled in the dependencies section, while the `fw4spl` folder must be built and compiled in the source section. You must have missed that the folder names were different: `fw4spl-deps` vs `fw4spl`. So you must do both.

"Compile dependencies in the console" means use the command prompt to compile the folder that was generated during the `fw4spl-deps` build. The building may be done with CMake for example as explained in the instructions.